# Ping from a mellanox switch to a server stuck

Tags: automation, ping, netmiko

So I am using netmiko to SSH into mellanox switch. I am then pinging a server from inside the switch using

> net_connect.send_command('ping '+ilo_ip)

But the problem is the ping is not stopping and the code is just stuck and is not moving forward.

I tried using write_channel instead of send_command but I get the output 'None' and then code just stuck there.

> net_connect.write_channel('ping '+ilo_ip)

I also tried

> "fast_cli": False

using it inside ConnectHandler inputs, but I didnt see any change.

Let me know how to use ping and get success or fail message using netmiko.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Netmiko has 'CNTL_SHIFT_6' embedded into it as a constant which you should be able to use:

[link to github netmiko](https://github.com/ktbyers/netmiko/blob/develop/netmiko/__init__.py#L46)

```
>>> from netmiko import CNTL_SHIFT_6
>>> CNTL_SHIFT_6
```

example code would be:

```
net_connect = ConnectHandler(**device)

pattern = re.escape('*')

output = net_connect.write_channel('ping '+ilo_ip) # or send_command

net_connect.write_channel(CNTL_SHIFT_6)
```

By default when you ping a network it continues to do so until you press **CTRL** and **C** at the same time to end the process.

So I think this is your solution.